# Turn off notification for certain messages

Tags: macos, mail.app, notifications

Is it possible to turn of notifications for certain mail messages (ex. newsletters)?

Comment: You should be a bit more specific, did you set rules already to post your newsletters in a folder?

Comment: Yes, I made a rule for all newsletters to be moved into a folder

Answer (score 3):

You can create a filter, which makes them automatically read, and therefor no message. A downside is that you need to create a filter (or rule) for every newsletter (or whatever you want to block) you receive. This way you will not receive a notification, but it isn't removed from your inbox.

Comment: +1 Good idea, but in my case I really need to know which newsletters I have not read yet. Note: I actually have one rule for all newsletters ;)

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. Its a workaround, but maybe you can also create a map with unread newsletters and read from there, instead the inbox. As you have such a folder (from the comment on the question) you can remove the mail from it, or, create two folders. I know its not a nice solution, but I dont think its possible to disable notifications for certain mails in the same inbox